# Camera photo not refreshing upon retake in android

Tags: java, android, camera, outputstream

How exactly does the android camera intent with "requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE" work? If I take a second picture, will the thumbnail refresh to the new one, or will it stay constant? (i.e. the uri will be rewritten)

The problem I'm running into is, I have a picture in an ImageSlider, I add an image to it on photo capture (it works), but when I close everything and take another picture, the same image is shown instead of the original. I checked all my outputstreams and it seems like I have flushed them, and I even tried deleting the temporary file created in the FileStream, but it doesn't work. See below code:

Camera Capture Class:

```
    // Captures the picture
public void captureCameraPhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_CAPTURE);
}
```

On activity result (retrieving thumbnail and displaying it)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final String name = "Take Photo";
    if (requestCode == ACTION_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
        try {
            bos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            OutputStream os = getActivity().openFileOutput("cardImage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            os.write(byteArray);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            File file = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("cardImage");
            Log.e("MADEFILE", file.toString());
            cardMap.put(name, file);
            // ADD SLIDER
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getActivity());
            textSliderView
                    .description("Custom Photo")
                    .image(cardMap.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterInside)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(new BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(sliderShow.getCurrentPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            try {
                sliderShow.removeSliderAt(6);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
            sliderShow.addSlider(textSliderView);
            sliderShow.movePrevPosition();
            sliderShow.movePrevPosition();
            currentOrder.add("cardImage");
            picturetaken = true;
            bitmap.recycle();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On exit of this dialogfragment:

```
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean deleteFile = getActivity().deleteFile("cardImage");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(deleteFile), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
```